# JSON.NET deserializes an object implementing IDictionary<TKey, TValue> as dictionary, how to force regular class serialization?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, json.net

Let's say I've defined an `interface`:

```
public interface IExtensibleObject : IDictionary<string, object>
{
    // Some members here, but it doesn't matter for this question
}
```

And I've designed a class which implements the whole interface:

```
public class Customer : IExtensibleObject
{
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     // IExtensibleObject implemented members
}
```

When I try to deserialize a JSON `string` to `Customer`, JSON.NET will access the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` indexer to set `Id` property (i.e. `instance["Id"] = value`):

```
Customer customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(@"{""Id"":""bcf66a92-00ea-4124-afa7-a6c200ae5886""}");
```

**Is there some built-in way of avoiding the whole behavior?**. I need to deserialize the whole object as a **regular object** even when it implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But perhaps you should reconsider using IDictionary (or any collection class/interface) as a base class with properties tacked on to it, for a lot of good reasons spelled out here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21694054/1220550

Comment: @PeterB It's not the case. In my case, I did it because certain entities should allow custom properties during run-time...

Comment: Okay, but you could also put those custom properties *in* a Dictionary type property of the Customer class. Normally the properties of a dictionary are all related to the dictionary, but you are using it more or less the other way around.

Comment: @PeterB More details: it's a `DynamicObject` :D

Comment: @PeterB It almost works like `ExpandoObject` but with compile-time properties

Comment: Another duplicate: [Json.Net cannot serialize property of a class derived from dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084536/json-net-cannot-serialize-property-of-a-class-derived-from-dictionary).

Comment: @dbc It has nothing to do with my Q&A...

Comment: As explained in that answer, if you mark your dictionary subtype with [`[JsonObject]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm) it will be deserialized as an object not a dictionary.  Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with custom contract resolver. Default contract resolver checks if class implements `IDictionary` and if so - serializes\deserializes it as such. You can change that:

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver {
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType) {
        // if type implements your interface - serialize it as object
        if (typeof(IExtensibleObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)) {
            return base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        }

        return base.CreateContract(objectType);
    }
}
```

And then just:

```
 var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings(); // or change default settings
 settings.ContractResolver = new CustomResolver();                        
 Customer customer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(@"{""Id"":""bcf66a92-00ea-4124-afa7-a6c200ae5886""}", settings);
```

Comment: I was going this way! but I was stuck on how to get default object converter!

Comment: In my case, the interface check isn't using `Any`, it's even easier than this: `typeof(IExtensibleObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)`. Why don't you just change this?

Comment: Nice! It worked flawlessly. In my case, I've inherited `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution ;)

Comment: I would still change `Any` with `typeof(IExtensibleObject).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)`. It's less cooler than using LINQ extension methods, but it's seems like it's the way to go ;)

Comment: You are welcome. Yes sure, IsAssignableFrom is the way to go, no idea why I used that way :)

Comment: Lol, because LINQ is the ring to rule them all ;D

Answer (score 1):

You'll find an answer to this here : [Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919797/json-convert-object-which-inherit-dictionary)

The only way I know is the same as answered in the link - you'll have to implement an custom JsonConverter

```
public class CustomerConverter : JsonConverter 
{
     public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
     {
        return objectType == typeof (Customer);
     }
     public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      {
            var eobj = (Customer) value;
            var temp = new Dictionary<string, object>(eobj);
            temp.Add("Id", eobj.Id);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, temp);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var temp = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(reader);
            var eobj = new Customer();
            foreach (var key in temp.Keys)
            {
                if (key == "Id")
                    eobj.Id = (Guid) temp[key];
                else
                    eobj.Add(key, temp[key]);
            }
            return eobj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've found another possible solution implementing a custom contract resolver which doesn't involve defining a new converter. And it's not flexible enough your solution because it's not just with `Id` but the issue affects all properties

Comment: I still need to try it, if it works I'll post as an answer!

Comment: Well you can define it with a contract resolver, but this will only define *which* properties will be serialized/deserialized - but will it change the **way** it is serialized?

Comment: The contract resolver approach seems cleaner in my case, it worked flawlessly. BTW I've upvoted your answer both because your effort and because it might be a valid approach in other scenarios!

Comment: Good to hear this would work out aswell, I didn't know that yet. I'll try this out aswell - maybe I'll need it sometime :)